# take value after execute query

Tags: sql, codeigniter

Im new to Codeigniter and its developing. i have tested a query succefully. But when i try to take voteid value im getting errors please help me.

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT voteid FROM Questions WHERE questionid = '$questionid'");

        echo $query->voteid; //im getting errors here.
```

Var_dump value of query

```
object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#18 (8) {
  ["conn_id"]=>
  resource(30) of type (mysql link persistent)
  ["result_id"]=>
  resource(39) of type (mysql result)
  ["result_array"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["result_object"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["custom_result_object"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["current_row"]=>
  int(0)
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(1)
  ["row_data"]=>
  NULL
```

Error

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_result::$voteid

Filename: models/questions_model.php
```

Comment: What says the error message? Where exactly occurs this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE questionid = '$id'");

echo $query->row()->voteid;
```

try this it should work

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns nothing because it's incorrect. Try: "SELECT voteid FROM Questions WHERE questionid = " . $questionid (I assume that $questionid is a variable of integer type)

Comment: yes it is integer value dude then can you edit right sql query here

Comment: The first problem is the wrong composition of a string you are trying to transfer as the query's parameter. The correct query should look like this: $query=$this->db->query("SELECT voteid FROM Questions WHERE questionid = " . $questionid); On the other hand, I would strongly recommend using standard CodeIgniter's functions to operate on databases. Check them out here: https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Comment: But if you stick at your way of doing it:
`$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   foreach ($query->result() as $row)
   {
      echo $row->title;
      echo $row->name;
      echo $row->body;
   }
}` "YOUR QUERY" is the string we've just corrected. Using this snipped you will be able to get a value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this type of writing your queries:

```
$this->db->select( 'voteid' );
$this->db->from  ( 'Questions' );
$this->db->where ( 'questionid', $questionid );

$result = $this->db->get( );

if ( $result->num_rows( ) > 0 ) 
{ 
    $row = $result->row( );
    $row->voteid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query=$this->db->query( "SELECT voteid FROM Questions WHERE questionid = $questionid" );
$row = $query->row(); 
return $row->voteid;
```

Using '$questionid' means that your variable is a string, but in this case it's an integer.